# Template class & overloaded comparison operators - Receiving error C4430

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing some code for an assignment and I'm having a bit of difficulty seeing what I'm doing wrong here.  I'm somewhat new to templates.  I am getting:

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

I'm trying to create a template class with overloaded <> comparison operators and a constructor that initializes to the value provided.

```
template <class T>
class GenericType
{
    T data;
public:
    operator<(const GenericType<T> & rvalue)
    {
        if (data < rvalue.data)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    operator>(const GenericType<T> & rvalue)
    {
        if (data > rvalue.data)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    GenericType(T inData)
    {
        data = inData;
    }

};

int main()
{
    GenericType <int>(5);
    GenericType <double>(1.3);
    GenericType <char>('a');
    GenericType <string>("sweet");
    GenericType <int>(4);
    GenericType <double>(2.7);
    GenericType <char>('A');
    GenericType <string>("dude");

}
```

Comment: Off topic: Your `operator<` and `>` should return `bool`.

Comment: Have you tried with `#include <string>` and fully qualifying `string` as `std::string`?

Comment: Your first post was my problem.  Thanks - it compiles now!  If you want to add as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but no point. This is a typo-style question that will be deleted in a few days.